# Como pego o valor de um hash no rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Eu tenho alguns checkboxs dentro de um form na view, que os valores estão sendo enviados para a controller por params para o index.

Obs. Estou mandando os valores dos checkbox do view index para ela mesma, preciso dos valores dos checkboxs em uma variável.

na controler estou recebendo os params assim:

```
 @post = params[:checkbox_array]
```

na view, está a ssim:

`post: <% @post %>`

depois que a página atualiza, aparece a variável com o segunte valor:

`post: {"2m"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3m"=>"3"}`

Eu quero apenas pegar todas as "keys" ou todos os "values" e atribuir a uma outra variável

Pelo que conheço deveria ser algo assim na controller:

`@variavel1 = @post.key` ou `@variavel2 = @post.values`

@post.select, @post.sample... também não funciona, quando accesso a página recebo "undefined method"

Oque devo fazer para filtrar esse hash que estou recebendo e ter uma saída como:

["2m", "2", "3m"] ou ["1", "2", "3"] ?

Answer (score 1):

Você está certo, o método que você procura é `keys` ou `values`,  exemplo:

```
{"2m"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3m"=>"3"}.keys
=> ["2m", "2", "3m"]

{"2m"=>"1", "2"=>"2", "3m"=>"3"}.values
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Espero ter ajudado.